# map namespace on XML for Google Maps API on android

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps

I have the following XML file for a View on Android.
As I am trying to integrate the Google Maps, I need to declare the namespace map, in order to set it's properties. Using like this, it looks like I cant declare the namespace inside the fragment.
I've also tried to declare the namespace after the namespace "android" (in the beggining of RelativeLayout) but the namespace is still not recognized on the fragment.

How can I solve this problem?

```
    <fragment xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/venues_map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        map:cameraZoom="13" />
```

Comment: Why did you downvote without even posting a comment?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I know, there is some bug that doesn't allow to put the map namespace properties inside the fragment if it not the only thing on the screen ( Meaning there are more views surround it).

Why wont you set your properties using code?
If you want to set zoom level do this:

```
cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(latlng).zoom(14.0f).build();
CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition);
map.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
```

Comment: That's what I have done, I've done it programatically. I just wanted to save some code when things can be configured using XML, that's why I was trying to figure out the way. But thanks for the tip